# VB.NET Iteratin to Disable Controls and Them Enabling some of them

Tags: vb.net, loops, controls, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to disable all controls in a form on .Load, except for a few. Since I am disabling a lot of controls and enabling only a few, I did not use something like if TypeOf Control Is ComboBox then... in my loop. I will just enable them one by one.

My problem is that when I enable them right after the loop, only the menustrip and button will work. Other (comboboxes and textboxes) will remain locked.

Here's this part in my code:

```
Private Sub AddForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim addformcontrol As Control
    For Each addformcontrol In Me.Controls
        addformcontrol.Enabled = False
    Next

    someComboBox.Enabled = True
    someTextBox.Enabled = True
    MenuStrip1.Enabled = True
    CleanAllButton.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing happens before the form loads, so why not set them however they need to be in the form designer?

Comment: It makes sense. I hadn't thoguht about it. It works nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these controls are in a container, such as a groupbox, and that control is disabled, enabling the child controls won't do the job.

Comment: That was exactly my problem. Thanks!